# what is the meaning of "sacred lots and prophets" here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

what is the meaning of "sacred lots and prophets" here?

> In the Hebrew Bible, the Witch of Endor is a woman Saul consulted to
>   summon the spirit of prophet Samuel in the 28th chapter of the First
>   Book of Samuel in order to receive advice against the Philistines in
>   battle after his prior attempts to consult God through **sacred lots and
>   prophets** had failed.[1][2] The witch is absent from the version of
>   that event recounted in the deuterocanonical Book of Sirach
>   (46:19–20).

from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Witch_of_Endor

Comment: Have you looked up the definitions of "lots" (a noun) "prophet" and "sacred".  If so please 1 ) copy and paste the definition that you are using into the question. 2) explain why you don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

From [*Collins English Dictionary – Complete and Unabridged, 12th Edition 2014*](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/lot), a relevant definition of *lot* is:

> 3. any object, such as a straw or slip of paper, drawn from others at random to make a selection or choice (esp in the phrase *draw* or *cast lots*)

An excerpt from https://carm.org/what-casting-lots-in-the-bible:

> Casting lots was a method used by the Jews of the Old Testament and by the Christian disciples prior to Pentecost to determine the will of God. Lots could be sticks with markings, stones with symbols, etc., which were thrown into a small area and then the result was interpreted. "The lot is cast into the lap, but its every decision is from the LORD," (Prov. 16:33). There are many instances of casting lots in the Bible.

Comment: does prophet here means "someone who tells what will happen in future"?

Comment: @soul Yes, exactly that.